# JUnit : AssertionFailedError, tests not found in

Tags: java, exception, junit

Here is my `testMethod` in question,

```
public class DetailsTest extends TestCase
{
    public void testGetQuotes() throws Exception
    {
        int bookSize = getBookSize();
        List<Details> detailList = getDetailLists();
        assertNotNull(bookSize);
        assertEquals(bookSize, detailList.size());
        assertNotNull(detailList.size());
    }
}
```

My class extends `JUnit : TestCase`, not sure what is wrong in here that is causing the issue...am using `junit 3.8.1`

**Update**
I have gone through similar questions on SO but it has not been very helpful.

**Update 2 :** StackTrace

```
1) warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1)junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in com.comp.Details.DetailsTest
    at junit.extensions.TestDecorator.basicRun(TestDecorator.java:22)
    at junit.extensions.TestSetup$1.protect(TestSetup.java:19)
    at junit.extensions.TestSetup.run(TestSetup.java:23)
```

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1,  Errors: 0

**Update 3:** I just had Details class in my testSuite and not DetailsTest, fixed it and now it works fine...one of those days...you see...

Comment: Would you post the stack trace?

Comment: Please include the stack trace and the class declaration. How are you running the test(s)?

Comment: Um... that's a different class.

Comment: How are you running JUnit?  In Eclipse?

Comment: Is DetailsTest an inner class in something? Looks like it from the fully qualified name.

Comment: @GarrettHall: I cannot run `junit` in eclipse as i need to make reference to App Server as I need to make some `EJB` calls from my Unit Test, am running it via home grown shell script.

Comment: @ftr: No it is not an inner class, it is an standalone junit test class.

Comment: Are you using TestRunner to run the test?

Comment: yes, i am using TestRunner to run the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you calling addTestSuite

```
suite.addTestSuite(DetailsTest.class)
```

where you should be calling addTest

```
suite.addTest(DetailsTest.class)
```

Comment: no i am running junit 3.8.1, i am rightly getting compilation error with @Test annotation being not recognized.

Comment: Check your runtime classpath against your compile time classpath. If your code isn't working, you aren't running with 3.8.1.

Comment: Checked that, it is running 3.8.1

Comment: i guess, this would solve the issue...i was calling `addTestSuite`, i will make the changes and update...

Comment: in my testsuite i was adding `Details.class` rather then DetailsTest.class and that was causing the problem, I have changed that, hopefully this should work, such a dump mistake and time sink...

Answer (score 2):

if your tests is in Android framework,please add this in your gradle file:

```
  defaultConfig {
     testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }

  packagingOptions {
     exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
  }
```

then it's ok.

Comment: it's `"androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"` now

Answer (score 0):

Use `JUnit4TestAdapter` to adapt your test class to new environment in case of migration.

It's useful when you get `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found` error.

ex: `TestSuiteEx` contains all my test case classes like this:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ 
    SampleTest.class,
    myTestCases.class
})
```

Then I added `AllTests` containing the following code:

```
public static Test suite() {
    TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("all tests");
    suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(TestSuiteEx.class));
    return suite;
}
```

It worked for me perfectly. :)

Happy coding.